# How can we use ES6 Fetch api to return json and other type of files like js?`

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, fetch-api

I use it for getting data from a REST API using response.json(); but i want to get data even if the response type is not json, it can he HTML, JS, CSS or anything.

Answer (score 1):

This really is basic stuff. Remember to read the docs.

```
fetch('endpoint/')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(textData => {
    console.log("Got data from endpoint", textData);
  })`
```